# Copying a random row from one table into another table at runtime

Tags: database, vb.net, runtime

I have a database that has two tables in it. One is a table of items (table1) and the other is the table of current items (table2).
On form load I need to generate a random amount of the items from table1 and populate table2 with them. I was trying to do something like this:

```
  While numberofitems >= 1
     Dim i As Integer

     index = myGenerator.Next(_minitem, _maxitem)

     i = _itemsListBindingSource.IndexOf(index)

     _bindingSource.Add(_itemsListBindingSource.Item(i))

     numberofitems -= 1

  End While

  Me.ItemsTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.Items2DataSet1.Items)
```

But that wasn't working at all. Can anyone offer any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing `.Items` from the call to `DataAdapter.Fill()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution (.net 3.5).  I created a typed dataset with a "Table1" and a "Table2" with tableadapters (in another file called dsMain.xsd).  I fill my "SourceTable" with data from "Table1" in the DB, then I grab random rows based on the number of rows in "SourceTable" and place them in "TargetTable".  Once "TargetTable" has my data in it, I commit it to the database using an "Update" statement.

```
    Dim SourceTable = (New dsMainTableAdapters.Table1TableAdapter).GetData
    Dim TargetTable As New dsMain.Table2DataTable

    Dim MyRandom As New Random()

    Const DesiredRowCount As Int32 = 20

    For i = 1 To DesiredRowCount
        Dim RandomRow = SourceTable(MyRandom.Next(0, SourceTable.Count))

        TargetTable.AddTable2Row(RandomRow(0))
    Next

    With (New dsMainTableAdapters.Table2TableAdapter)
        .Update(TargetTable) 'Save my data to the DB'
    End With
```